# The containers become shorter instead of overflowing

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have made a messaging web app a while back and this summer i tried to make another with a bit of a different structure but ran into this issue where the spans' (messages') height shrunk instead of overflowing with scroll, and if i set a min-height they wouldn't get taller when the message was longer, so i used the source code of the old one and changed it a bit, but had the same issue. I would really like to know why this is happening and how to solve it.

I put the code on github, to be easier to see/try: [https://github.com/Konstei/stack-overflow-code/](https://github.com/Konstei/stack-overflow-code).

I also made it into a running website using github's pages: https://konstei.github.io/stack-overflow-code/new/, [https://konstei.github.io/stack-overflow-code/old/](https://konstei.github.io/stack-overflow-code/old/messages.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have referred your code and the issue is you have set `overflow: hidden` on `*{}` global selector. Since your direct **span** element after message-area div hasn't specified any overflow property, the overflow property from your global selector gets applied whose value is `hidden` and hence the overflowing content from inner span is being hidden. Just remove that property from your global selector and it should work.

Comment: oh wow thank you a lot, i wouldn't have realized; i was racking my brain trying to solve this and the solution was this simple 

Comment: especially when you are facing CSS or HTML or JS related problems it is always better to use dev tools/console to inspect elements and tweak styles to see what may be going wrong. IT helps you a lot.

Comment: i did look at the computed css styles, but they were pretty much the same as the css file, it was on me that i didn't realize that it didn't scale because of the inherited overflow